# Reporting Services Report Builder, get a specific number and add to all other lines

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder

I'm working with Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 3.0. I ran into a problem I can't solve myself.

I've got the following table:

```
ID | price
----------
0  |   5
1  |  10
2  |   7
3  |   9
4  |   6
```

What I want to do is to subtract the price from ID 0, from every other ID.

The result should look similar to this:

```
ID | price
----------
0  |   0
1  |   5
2  |   2
3  |   4
4  |   1
```

I think "lookup" could do the job, I just can't get it to work.

I tried:

```
=Fields!price.Value-Lookup(0,Fields!ID.Value,Fields!price.Value, "DataSet1")
```

Is there any way to get to this result?

(In C# I would use a Dictionary and do something like for(...){ID[i]-ID[0]} If that helps to explain what I mean)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution:

```
Sum(iif(Fields!ID.Value=0,Fields!price.Value,0),"DataSet1")
```

This should give the correct result, but Im not sure if it works everytime.
Is there another (better) way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works exactly as expected but should give you an idea on one use for [RunningValue](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159136(v=sql.100).aspx)

```
= Fields!price.Value - RunningValue(iif(Fields|ID.Value = 0 ,Fields!price.Value,0), Sum, "DataSet1")
```